# Using GParted to Extend Size of Mac OSX Hard Disk

Tags: macos, resize, virtual-machine, virtualbox, hard-drive

My computer runs Windows 8. I have a VM Virtual Box Instance of Mac OSX. I made the hard disk 20GB at first, but now I need it to be bigger. I made a back up of the hard disk and then proceeded to resize the original hard disk to 30GB. Now I am trying to actually be able to use the extra 10GB I have added.

First I tried to do this through Disk Utility on the actual VM to no avail. When I tried to resize the partition to use the entire available space, and then clicked "apply" it simply did nothing. When I tried to resize the partition to use any less than the entire available space, it gave me the error `MediaKit reports partition (map) too small`.

Now I have loaded a GParted ISO onto the VM, and have been trying to use that to resize the hard disk but this is also to no avail. Here is an image of the situation with GParted:

[image]

When I try to resize "Yosemite Erase" (the hard disk) it says that the minimum and maximum space that it can take up are the same, 19.20GB, which is what it currently is. I tried moving the "Recovery HD" over to the other side of the unallocated space. But I still was unable to resize "Yosemite Erase" for the same reason; it just doesn't let me.

The warning "YosemiteErase" has says `Unable to read the contents of this file system! Because of this some operations may be unavailable. The cause might be a missing software package. The following list of software packages is required for hfs+ file support: hfsprogs.`

Does anyone know what I should do?

**EDIT:**

Nevermind. It turns out that GParted does a "fix" of the hard disk before the GUI boots which I originally had disregarded. However it turns out that when I try to extend the size of the hard disk in Disk Utility, it now works perfectly because of this fix.

Comment: I had to use GParted to format the unallocated to `/dev/sda4` as `hfs+` because `Disk Utility` kept throwing an error when partitioning as `unallocated`.  But `Disk Utility` merged the 2 partitions perfectly after that.

Comment: Oh @user2426679, thank you! After hours of fruitless searching, that's the answer I was looking for! It's unbelievable Disk Utility can't simply expand a partition into empty space... *smh*

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue trying to install Kali Linux on a Mac.

I installed "hfsprogs" as the error suggested:

```
sudo apt-get install hfsprogs
```

...but the error in Gparted never went away and it never showed the "used" amount on the hfs+ share, despite Gparted showing that the plugin was now installed.

Gparted also tried to "fix" it for me as well, that seemed to have no effect.

I ended up booting into OSX and using Disk Utility to resize the HFS+ partition.

I suspect that the hfsprogs package allows some info about HFS+ partitions in Gparted, but doesn't enable resizing partitions.